# WatchOS 2 Complication Scheduled Update In Background

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchos-2, apple-watch-complication

So, after sooo so much testing and online research, I have to give up and ask for help. WatchOS 2 complications.

So I am trying to create a basic complication that shows the time at the time of update.

I am aware that update in background are budgeted so I am attempting to update the time every 10 mins. Hopefully as collecting an NSDate is simple, that won't cause me to go 'over budget' what ever that means.

I am for now ignoring time travel and providing a timeline. Instead I am simply filling out the large module template with the current time in:

```
func getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {
```

I then have this:

```
func getNextRequestedUpdateDateWithHandler(handler: (NSDate?) -> Void){
    handler(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60*10));
}
```

And this:

```
func requestedUpdateDidBegin(){
    NSLog("requestedUpdateDidBegin")
    let complicationServer = CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()
    for complication in complicationServer.activeComplications {
        complicationServer.reloadTimelineForComplication(complication)
    }
}
```

The update never ever occurs though. 
Only by launching the extension and running the same code as 4 lines above, can i get the complication to update.
From looking at the logs, all that happens after a forced update is that the method getNextRequestedUpdateDateWithHandler gets called but nothing else.

Any suggestions or anything that I am obviously missing? Thanks very much for reading.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I tried to use an NSTimer as alternative but it results just in a memory read error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you need to implement:

```
func getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: ((CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void))
```

The method you have implemented `getTimelineEntriesForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, beforeDate...` is only called when the complication server is gathering timeline entries for forward time travel.

Given the scenario you describe, I would strongly recommend supporting forward time travel by implementing:

```
func getSupportedTimeTravelDirectionsForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: (CLKComplicationTimeTravelDirections) -> Void) {
    handler([.Forward])
}
```

And

```
func getTimelineEndDateForComplication(complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: (NSDate?) -> Void) {
    let date: NSDate = // Your date
    handler(date)
}
```

Comment: This won't help me unfortunately because the data i want to collect it only available at the present time of updating, and in the past. not future data is available. The plan it to use health kit to collect pedometer data

Comment: Well, putting aside that your use case doesn't support forward time travel, have you tried implementing the method that I suggested first up `getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication`?

Comment: In the original question i have said that I'm not doing time travel and that i have already tried implementing getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication, getNextRequestedUpdateDateWithHandler, and requestedUpdateDidBegin

Comment: I must have misunderstood. I don't see any reference in your question to `getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication`. Complications have worked as documented for me, but without seeing your source I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I've made a mistake in the question, have corrected it. How often are you finding you are able to call an update? From what I've read 30mins is about the max even if the update is instant

Comment: I haven't tried anything more frequent than every thirty minutes. Your other option is `transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo:`, but that depends on your phone app being active, and is also budgeted.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately because Im trying to do a health kit query, I can run it on the iPhone in the background :( oh well

Comment: *can't run it in background, and I can't call HKSampleQuery in getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication or requestUpdateDidBegin